# Using radio button to show/hide div + validation with jqueryvalidation.org

Tags: jquery, radio-button, jquery-validate, show-hide, hidden

I am trying to show/hide a div and then validate within the shown div and not validate the hidden div.

- If `Yes` is chosen in the radio `id_question`, then display the div `id="row_id_number"` & validate.
- If `No` is chosen in the radio `id_question`, then display the div `id="row_contact_method"` & validate.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
            $().ready(function() {

                $("#id_frm").validate({
                    rules: {

                        "id_question": {
                           required: true
                        },
                        "id_number": {
                            required: true,
                            minlength: 10,
                            minlength: 10
                        },
                        "contact_method": {
                            required: true
                        }


                    },
                    messages: {
                        "id_question": {
                            required: "Please choose if you have an ID or not."
                        },
                        "id_number": {
                            required: "Please Enter ID."
                        },
                        "contact_method": {
                            required: "Please choose a contact method."
                        }               

                    },

            });


        });
    </script>



<style type="text/css">
.error {
    color: #F00;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="" id="id_frm" method="post" name="id_frm">

        <div id="row_id_question">
                <label>Do you have an ID?</label>
                <input type="radio" name="id_question" value="Yes" id="id_question">Yes &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="id_question" value="No" id="id_question">No<br/>
                <label for="id_question" class="error" generated="true"></label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br/><br/>

        <!--display & validate if yes-->
        <div id="row_id_number">
                <label>Enter ID number</label>
                <input name="id_number" type="text" id="id_number" maxlength="10" value=""><br/>
                <label for="id_number" class="error" generated="true"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--end yes-->

        <br/><br/>

        <!--display & validate if no -->
        <div id="row_contact_method">
                <label>Preferred Contact Method</label><br/>
                <input type="radio" name="contact_method" value="Email" id="contact_method">Email &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="contact_method" value="Phone" id="contact_method">Phone &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="radio" name="contact_method" value="Postal" id="contact_method">Postal<br/>
                <label for="contact_method" class="error" generated="true"></label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--end no-->

        <input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit">
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$().ready` is not the same as `$.ready`

Comment: jQuery Validate automatically ignores hidden fields so you don't need to alter your rules at all.  Simply show/hide the rows based on your radio buttons and the proper validation will occur automatically based on what's showing.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the jQuery Validate plugin will ignore hidden fields (not validate anything that's hidden), so simply show/hide your `div` elements and let the validation follow along automatically.  (There is no need for any modifications to your validation rules to achieve this.)

```
$('[name="id_question"]').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Yes") {
        $('#row_id_number').show();
        $('#row_contact_method').hide();
    } else {
        $('#row_id_number').hide();
        $('#row_contact_method').show();
    }
});

$("#id_frm").validate({ .... });
```

Since you never said what it's supposed to look like when the form initially loads, I've made both rows hidden until the radio is selected.  You can easily alter the CSS as needed...

```
<div id="row_id_number" style="display:none"> .... </div>
```

and

```
<div id="row_contact_method" style="display:none"> .... </div>
```

**Working DEMO with jQuery Validation:  http://jsfiddle.net/mvzusbh7/**

---

[As per jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), the syntax of your DOM ready handler is ***"not recommended"***.

```
$().ready(function() { ....  // <- not recommended
```

should be...

```
$(document).ready(function () { ....
```

or...

```
$(function() { ....
```

---

You've also accidentally listed the same rule twice...

```
"id_number": {
    required: true,
    minlength: 10,
    minlength: 10 // <- same rule listed twice
},
```